# General Protection Fault encountered when executing SYSRET

Tags: assembly, x86-64, qemu, osdev

I am currently working on my own 64-bit x86-64 kernel, and now trying to get to ring 3 by executing the instruction SYSRET. However it fails and I could not figure out the reason

Here is how I set up my get:

```
uint64 gdt[6]; // gdt data struct
gdt[0] = 0UL;                   // dummy
gdt[1] = 0x00a0980000000000UL;  // kernel code
gdt[2] = 0x00c0920000000000UL;  // kernel data
gdt[3] = 0UL;                   // reserved
gdt[4] = 0x00c0f20000000000UL;  // user data
gdt[5] = 0x00a0f80000000000UL;  // user code

struct gdtp {
  uint16 size;
  uint64 addr;
} __attribute__((packed)) _gdtp; // gdt pointer

_gdtp.size = 8 * 6 - 1;
_gdtp.addr = (uint64)&gdt[0]; // setting gdt pointer

__asm__ __volatile__ ("lgdt 0x1031d0"); // load the gdt pointer, 0x1031d0 is the gdt pointer address
```

After that I try to execute the instruction SYSRET:

```
global jump_usermode
extern user_test
jump_usermode:
;enable system call extensions that enables sysret and syscall
    mov rcx, 0xc0000082 ; LSTAR
    wrmsr
    mov rcx, 0xc0000080 ; ENABLE SYSCALL/SYSRET
    rdmsr
    or eax, 1
    wrmsr
    mov rcx, 0xc0000081 ; SETTING STAR[63:48], for SS & CS
    rdmsr
    mov edx, 0x00180008
    wrmsr
    mov rcx, user_test ; to be loaded into RIP
    mov r11, 0x202 ; to be loaded into EFLAGS
    o64 sysret
```

I ran the code using qemu, here is the registers output:

BEFORE SYSRET:

```
Servicing hardware INT=0x20
   192: v=20 e=0000 i=0 cpl=0 IP=0008:0000000000101852 pc=0000000000101852 SP=0000:0000000000110ef0 env->regs[R_EAX]=0000000000000010
RAX=0000000000000010 RBX=0000000000000000 RCX=0000000000000008 RDX=00000000000003f8
RSI=0000000000000030 RDI=00000000000003f8 RBP=0000000000110fe0 RSP=0000000000110ef0
R8 =0000000000000000 R9 =0000000000000000 R10=0000000000000000 R11=0000000000000000
R12=0000000000000000 R13=0000000000000000 R14=0000000000000000 R15=0000000000000000
RIP=0000000000101852 RFL=00000212 [----A--] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0000 0000000000000000 00000000 00000000
CS =0008 0000000000000000 00000000 00209800 DPL=0 CS64 [---]
SS =0000 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0000 0000000000000000 00000000 00000000
FS =0000 0000000000000000 00000000 00000000
GS =0000 0000000000000000 00000000 00000000
LDT=0000 0000000000000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 0000000000000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS64-busy
GDT=     0000000000100284 0000000f
IDT=     00000000001031e0 00000fff
CR0=80000011 CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=0000000000105000 CR4=00000020
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=0000000000000010 CCD=0000000000000001 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000500
```

0xd(#GP) and 0xc(#SS) after SYSRET:

```
check_exception old: 0xffffffff new 0xd
   193: v=0d e=0000 i=0 cpl=3 IP=002b:00000000001013bd pc=00000000001013bd SP=0023:0000000000110e90 env->regs[R_EAX]=00000000000003fd
RAX=00000000000003fd RBX=0000000000000000 RCX=00000000001019ee RDX=00000000000003fd
RSI=0000000000000030 RDI=00000000000003fd RBP=0000000000110e90 RSP=0000000000110e90
R8 =0000000000000000 R9 =0000000000000000 R10=0000000000000000 R11=0000000000000202
R12=0000000000000000 R13=0000000000000000 R14=0000000000000000 R15=0000000000000000
RIP=00000000001013bd RFL=00000202 [-------] CPL=3 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0000 0000000000000000 00000000 00000000
CS =002b 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00a0fb00 DPL=3 CS64 [-RA]
SS =0023 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00c0f300 DPL=3 DS   [-WA]
DS =0000 0000000000000000 00000000 00000000
FS =0000 0000000000000000 00000000 00000000
GS =0000 0000000000000000 00000000 00000000
LDT=0000 0000000000000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 0000000000000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS64-busy
GDT=     00000000001031a0 0000002f
IDT=     00000000001031e0 00000fff
CR0=80000011 CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=0000000000105000 CR4=00000020
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=0000000000000005 CCD=00000000000003fd CCO=ADDL
EFER=0000000000000501
check_exception old: 0xd new 0xc
   194: v=08 e=0000 i=0 cpl=3 IP=002b:00000000001013bd pc=00000000001013bd SP=0023:0000000000110e90 env->regs[R_EAX]=00000000000003fd
RAX=00000000000003fd RBX=0000000000000000 RCX=00000000001019ee RDX=00000000000003fd
RSI=0000000000000030 RDI=00000000000003fd RBP=0000000000110e90 RSP=0000000000110e90
R8 =0000000000000000 R9 =0000000000000000 R10=0000000000000000 R11=0000000000000202
R12=0000000000000000 R13=0000000000000000 R14=0000000000000000 R15=0000000000000000
RIP=00000000001013bd RFL=00000202 [-------] CPL=3 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0000 0000000000000000 00000000 00000000
CS =002b 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00a0fb00 DPL=3 CS64 [-RA]
SS =0023 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00c0f300 DPL=3 DS   [-WA]
DS =0000 0000000000000000 00000000 00000000
FS =0000 0000000000000000 00000000 00000000
GS =0000 0000000000000000 00000000 00000000
LDT=0000 0000000000000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 0000000000000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS64-busy
GDT=     00000000001031a0 0000002f
IDT=     00000000001031e0 00000fff
CR0=80000011 CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=0000000000105000 CR4=00000020
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=0000000000000005 CCD=00000000000003fd CCO=ADDL
EFER=0000000000000501
check_exception old: 0x8 new 0xc
```

After modification:

```
void user_test() {
  for (;;) ;
}
```

Error message:

```
   280: v=0c e=0000 i=0 cpl=3 IP=002b:00000000001019c2 pc=00000000001019c2 SP=0023:0000000000110fd0 env->regs[R_EAX]=0000000000000000
RAX=0000000000000000 RBX=0000000000000000 RCX=00000000001019be RDX=0000000000180008
RSI=000000000000000a RDI=00000000000003f8 RBP=0000000000110fd0 RSP=0000000000110fd0
R8 =0000000000000000 R9 =0000000000000000 R10=0000000000000000 R11=0000000000000202
R12=0000000000000000 R13=0000000000000000 R14=0000000000000000 R15=0000000000000000
RIP=00000000001019c2 RFL=00000202 [-------] CPL=3 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0000 0000000000000000 00000000 00000000
CS =002b 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00a0fb00 DPL=3 CS64 [-RA]
SS =0023 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00c0f300 DPL=3 DS   [-WA]
DS =0000 0000000000000000 00000000 00000000
FS =0000 0000000000000000 00000000 00000000
GS =0000 0000000000000000 00000000 00000000
LDT=0000 0000000000000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 0000000000000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS64-busy
GDT=     00000000001031a0 0000002f
IDT=     00000000001031e0 00000fff
CR0=80000011 CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=0000000000105000 CR4=00000020
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=0000000000000000 CCD=0000000000000501 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000501
check_exception old: 0xc new 0xc
   281: v=08 e=0000 i=0 cpl=3 IP=002b:00000000001019c2 pc=00000000001019c2 SP=0023:0000000000110fd0 env->regs[R_EAX]=0000000000000000
RAX=0000000000000000 RBX=0000000000000000 RCX=00000000001019be RDX=0000000000180008
RSI=000000000000000a RDI=00000000000003f8 RBP=0000000000110fd0 RSP=0000000000110fd0
R8 =0000000000000000 R9 =0000000000000000 R10=0000000000000000 R11=0000000000000202
R12=0000000000000000 R13=0000000000000000 R14=0000000000000000 R15=0000000000000000
RIP=00000000001019c2 RFL=00000202 [-------] CPL=3 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0000 0000000000000000 00000000 00000000
CS =002b 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00a0fb00 DPL=3 CS64 [-RA]
SS =0023 0000000000000000 ffffffff 00c0f300 DPL=3 DS   [-WA]
DS =0000 0000000000000000 00000000 00000000
FS =0000 0000000000000000 00000000 00000000
GS =0000 0000000000000000 00000000 00000000
LDT=0000 0000000000000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 0000000000000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS64-busy
GDT=     00000000001031a0 0000002f
IDT=     00000000001031e0 00000fff
CR0=80000011 CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=0000000000105000 CR4=00000020
DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 
DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400
CCS=0000000000000000 CCD=0000000000000501 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000501
```

OBJDUMP output:

```
00000000001019be <user_test>:
  1019be: 55                            pushq   %rbp
  1019bf: 48 89 e5                      movq    %rsp, %rbp
  1019c2: eb fe                         jmp     0x1019c2 <user_test+0x4>
```

Comment: `v=0d e=0000 i=0 cpl=3 IP=002b:00000000001013bd` CPL=3 means it got to Ring 3 (user mode). CS of 0x002b suggests that as well .  `v=0d` is a #GP (General protection fault). e=0000 is the error code, and a value of 0 suggests the #GP wasn't segment related. Have you looked to see what instruction is at address 0x1013bd to get an idea what the cause was. Did you use a privileged instruction in ring 3 like `hlt` (as an example). That would cause a #GP.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but why are you hardcoding the GDT record pointer in `__asm__ __volatile__ ("lgdt 0x1031d0");`? You can pass the GDT record pointer (_gdtp) into inline assembly and it will fill in the address. You could use `__asm__ ("lgdt %0" : : "m" (_gdtp) : "memory");`

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thank you for your helping! The #GP is indeed caused by executing an inport instruction after it jumped to ring 3. However, now I try to stop the kernel by adding a "for (;;) ;" statement, but the instruction "jump $" (EB FE) will cause a #SS fault now.

Comment: That's weird, the only instruction in `user_test` that should be able to cause that is the `push %rbp` which actually stores to stack memory.  Unless a timer interrupt fires or something and there's an #SS because of something involving the TSS.  (And this happens while user-space is in the infinite loop.)

Comment: I believe @PeterCordes is correct. Before `v=0c` exception did you get an interrupt come in? You can check the QEMU log. When entering ring 3 you did `mov r11, 0x202` before the SYSRET. 0x202 has bit 9 set which is the Interrupt flag. So when you enter ring 3 interrupts will be on. In order for you to handle interrupts in a ring other than 0 you will need a proper TSS (Task segment) and its selector loaded with the `ltr` instruction before entering ring 3. If you want to test if this is likely the issue change `mov r11, 0x202` to `mov r11, 0x002`. This will enter ring 3 with interrupt off.

Comment: I did an experiment in QEMU and could replicate the #SS(0) if the task register isn't loaded with something that is valid. The invalid TSS happens to be at the bottom of memory where the real mode interrupt table (IVT) is. The value in the TSS for RSP0 (the ring 0 stack to be used) ends up being non-canonical and thus the #SS(0).

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that I have not set up TSS correctly. Notice that in 64-bit mode TSS-pointer is 16byte, while CS/SS Selector from STAR registers are 8byte. Thank you so much, Michael Petch and Peter Cordes!